# How do I call a method in a routes file from a public javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, post

I'm playing with a template using mongoose, express, node and mongodb. There is information passed from jade to mongo through forms, but I'm attempting to send HTML to mongo after a jQuery function has manipulated it, yet I can't even seem to call `app.post()` at all, let alone feed it anything.

In my public/javascript.js file:

```
var element =  $('.whatever').html();
$.post("post/529be9b307cc42a259000001", element) //The number is :id which is in the url
```

And in my routes/posts.js file:

```
module.exports = function (app) {


app.post("/post/:id", loggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
   var id = req.param('id');
   console.log("WHY DOESNT THIS MESSAGE SHOW UP IN TERMINAL??!") 
   console.log(element);      
});

...
```

I understand this is a total newb question, but how do I just call `app.post()` from the public JS file?  All the other `app.get` and `app.post` methods are called successfully using jade like this:

```
 form(method='post', action="/post/" + post.id)
    textarea(name='text')
    input(type='submit', value='Save')
```

And in the routes/posts.js: `var text = req.param('text');` picks up the info.  Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't this line already fail with an error (why the curly brackets?)? `$.post("post/529be9b307cc42a259000001", {element})`

Comment: Yes it did, that was a typo.  I fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.post()`, and everything within your routes files are executed on the server, and thus not available to your client side Javascript.

When you execute the Ajax request or submit a form POST, you are actually making another request to the server, similar to the GET request you did to initially load the page.

In this case, I believe you problem is in the **relative URL** in `$.post("post/529be9b307cc42a259000001", ...)`, as this would request the route for `yoursite.com/current_url/post/:id`. Notice the difference between the `action="/post/"` in the form you created in Jade and `$.post("post/:id",...)`?

Unless the view you are currently working on is at the root (i.e yoursite.com), what you probably want is an **absolute path** `$.post("/post/529be9b307cc42a259000001", .. )` with a leading slash to route your POST request to `yoursite.com/post/:id`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The view I'm working with is `http://localhost:3000/post/529be9b307cc42a259000001`.  I believe I'm posting something because this `POST /post/529be9b307cc42a259000001 302 11ms - 40b` keeps popping up in terminal.  Yet when I search mongo, I see no new changes to the db.  And in the routes/posts.js file no console.logs r called.  Can u think of any $.post function that would show up somewhere?  I just want proof of touching the server side from the client side, as desperate as that may sound.

Comment: if `POST /post/##` shows up in the nodejs terminal then the request is successfully reaching the server. 302 is 'Found'. I believe @jwags is right about `loggedIn`, have you tried simply `app.post('/post/:id', function (req, res, next) { ...} );` ?

Comment: Getting a 500 error.  Thanks for trying tho.  I think it's time to start over.  Can you post HTML without using a form?  Do u know of any examples?

Comment: I think a 500 error is an improvement. The AJAX method you are using and the form POST are the two options from within an html page.

Comment: I think I'm getting close.  I've got the html all the way to the model, but when calling `this.update(query, body, function (err, numAffected) {` I'm getting `Error: no post to modify`

Comment: Nice going. It would be difficult to comment on that without seeing that section of the code, however. If you're still stuck, your best bet is to post it as a separate question since you've worked past the POST stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by [@Evan Cordeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2097523/evan-cordeiro) you need to make sure that you are actually making the request to the correct URL.  Another thing to ensure is that the "loggedIn" function is calling it's callback.  A third requirement is that you have used all of the correct [middlewares](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware).